# Separating and reuse project several times

Tags: go, clean-architecture, modular

I wanna separating and make core for all projects(I don't need write it from scratch) and every time I need a features of core only import it on my projects but I don't have good idea to do it ...
Also I use  [this](https://medium.com/@manakuro/clean-architecture-with-go-bce409427d31) to make my every core (as Auth)...
I made Auth for my project as clean architecture but I don't know How I can reuse it several times And every time want to change it without destroyed another projects that use it(as Auth , Permissions , ...)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you check out [go modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules).
You can make your "core" an own module. Import this module into your other projects and even lock for desired versions.

Comment: Thanks ...I want every project dependency to be unique for it and I can change it to every need to change ... did you think is good way?and also it doesn't fill a lot space on my disk

Comment: I am not sure I understood you. You are able to use different versions of the core module in different projects